# Equivalent of fwrite for char * for binary data

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Is there an equivalent to fwrite for writing to a char * array? I tried stringstream but it didn't seem to be doing exactly the same. I can use memcpy, but I'm losing track of the count...

**Clarification** Data to be written potentially has nul in it. I want to

```
write(array, &someint, 4);
write(array, &bunchofdata, sizeof(bunchofdata));
write(array, somestring, somestring.length());
```

and just keep incrementing the offset.

Comment: "I can use memcpy, but I'm losing track of the count..." How do you mean you are losing track of the count? If the char-array in question is zero-terminated, you could use `strcpy`.

Comment: `memcpy`, or perhaps `memmove`. Or `std::copy`, since you're in C++. If you can't manage to keep track of the count, `fwrite` isn't going to work, either.

Comment: Is there a remotely-related example of what you're trying to do, but failing? Are you basically looking or an in-memory `FILE*` (circa the `fwrite` nuance) or something similar? And is it possible that a simple `std::vector<char>` and its plethora of member functionality it offers would suffice for what you need ?

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to create a stream buffer writing to a fixed size buffer. Once you have a stream buffer you can write to it using the normal stream operations after constructing an `std::ostream` for it. For example:

```
struct membuf
    : std::streambuf
{
    membuf(char* base, std::size_t size) { this->setp(base, base + size); }
    char* end() { return this->pptr(); }
};

int main()
{
    char         buffer[12345];
    membuf       sbuf(buffer, sizeof(buffer);
    std::ostream out(&sbuf);
    out << "hello, world\n";
    std::cout << "wrote " << (sbuf.end() - buffer) << " bytes\n";
}
```

Obviously, you could also use the unformatted stream operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly pass in the size and count, you can just create a light-weight wrapper (either inline function or macro) around memcpy that keeps the same parameters as fwrite.

```c
#define memwrite(buffer, size, count, destination) \
    memcpy(destination, buffer, (size) * (count))
```